# Using an image as a link

Tags: html, css

So I feel like I'm doing everything correctly, but can't get my images to link to my other page.

My html:

```
<div id="picbox" >
   <div id="first"><a href="classes.htm"><img src="images/skyrim edit1.png" width="200px" height="500px"></a></div>
   <div id="second"><a href="skilltree.htm"><img src="images/skyrim edit2.jpg" width="200px" height="500px"></a></div>
   <div id="third"><a href="equipment.htm"><img src="images/Daedric_Armor_(Skyrim).jpg" width="200px" height="500px"></a></div>
   <div id="fourth"><a href="locations.htm"><img src="images/skyrimmap.jpg" width="200px" height="500px"></a></div>
   <div id="fifth"><a href="tips.htm"><img src="images/skyrimlogo.png" width="200px" height="500px"></a></div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
#picbox{
position: relative;
top: 300px;
width: 100%;
height: 600px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -6;}

#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth
{border: 2px solid orange;
height: 500px;
width: 200px;
margin-top: 25px;}

#first{
float: left;
margin-left: 100px;}

#second{
float: left;
margin-left: 175px;}

#third{
float: left;
margin-left: 175px;}

#fourth{
float: left;
margin-left: 175px;}

#fifth{
float: left;
margin-left: 175px;}
```

So any help would be greatly appreciated. I've got 5 divs within a larger placeholder div. I'm trying to put images into the smaller divs and have them link to other pages

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your HTML or CSS (apart from z-index: -6) - this should work. Do you have any other CSS?

Comment: I made you a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XcSba/

Comment: Yes I've got quite a bit more.

Comment: You should avoid using negative z-indexes.

Comment: The negative `z-index` is what does it here. Since (I assume) you have no other positioning context, your div is below the `body`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of z-index index is affecting your hyperlink not to appear above on the stack. Try changing the value of z-value and retry

Comment: Awesome this did the trick! I'm new to z-indexes and I was wanting it all to scroll under my header. I altered the body z-index to -999 so it is always on the bottom. Thank you all.